# Учитывает ли високосный код класс Calendar java

Tags: java

Будет ли учитывать високосные года поле типа Calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Calendar` не имеет метода для проверки високосного года.

Такой метод существует в классе-потомке: [`GregorianCalendar::isLeapYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear(int)):

> `public boolean isLeapYear(int year)`
> Determines if the given year is a leap year. Returns true if the given year is a leap year. To specify BC year numbers, 1 - year number must be given. For example, year BC 4 is specified as -3.
> **Parameters:**
> `year` - the given year.
> **Returns:**
> `true` if the given year is a leap year; `false` otherwise.

---

*Примечание:* Классы для работы с датами `Calendar` / `GregorianCalendar` / `Date` являются *устаревшими* после выхода Java 8 в марте 2014, где был реализован новый функциональный [Java Date/Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/datetime/index.html).